# Data type int in Oracle

Tags: oracle

On several occasions now I have come across CREATE TABLE statements in Oracle where the data type INT is used. 
Aren't only the following numeric data types valid in the Oracle database (that's what the official documentation says at least) - NUMBER, BINARY_INTEGER, BINARY_FLOAT?

If I do the following, it does work:

create table test ( i int);

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: These are ANSI data types and represented as numbers, as explained in the documentation:  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: `binary_integer` isn't a valid SQL data type. It's from PL/SQL where it is the [old name for `pls_integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-9517B7AC-9CEA-4C36-A454-52588BEEBE8F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using data types described in the ANSI standard. Oracle supports those as well. This is discussed in this section of the docs.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLQR/sqlqr06001.htm#SQLQR954

```
ANSI-supported data types

{ CHARACTER [VARYING] (size)
| { CHAR | NCHAR } VARYING (size)
| VARCHAR (size)
| NATIONAL { CHARACTER | CHAR }
     [VARYING] (size)
| { NUMERIC | DECIMAL | DEC }
     [ (precision [, scale ]) ]
| { INTEGER | INT | SMALLINT }
| FLOAT [ (size) ]
| DOUBLE PRECISION
| REAL
}
```

I personally use INTEGER all the time as a shorthand of NUMBER(*,0).

Comment: And [this table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF55581) shows the mapping between ANSI types and Oracle types

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.